# Is f1(const char* str) different from f1(char* str) when applying SWIG to C++?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am applying SWIG to convert C++ library to Python library.

I have a header file and a source file (trivial things are omitted):

test.h

```
void f1(char* str);
```

test.cc

```
void f1(const char* str) {
    /* do something */
}
```

When I build it, it does not throw any errors or warnings about such a mismatch.

But when I import my module generated by SWIG in Python:

```
>>> import (MYMODULE)
 ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libMYMODULE.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2f14str12iii
```

An error like the above occurs.

But, after fixing the header and the source to have the same arguments, **`const char* str`**, the error has been solved.

What I wonder is, then, why does C++ compiler and builder does not throw an error or a warning, put the thing becomes a problem in SWIG and Python.

Comment: Also, something like `echo _ZN2f14str12iii | c++filt` will tell you which is missing by undecorating the name (its not clear to me if its the `char*` or `const char *` that's missing). It seems like it should fail during compile/link of the native module, and not during the conversion to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `char*` and `const char*` are different types.

You've declared two overloaded functions, and only defined one. That's not an error, as long as you don't try to call or otherwise use the undefined one. If you do, you'll get a link-time error; since you've built a dynamic library, that will only be detected when the library is loaded - in this case, by your Python interpreter.